# VBA Display Adjacent Data next to Search in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

Long story short I've been searching for three days on a solution to this and just can't find a website or post on here that is like my situation.

I would like to have a form with a textbox search for a number, like "003.30", and below have another textbox display the cell related information. My table's (titled icd9_codes) with two columns, "BETTER_CODES" and "LONG_DESCRIPTION". In a form (or what would be better?), I enter in a textbox my ICD code, and then the long descrption of that ICD code would appear in another textbox below.

I'm still new to vba, and what I learned in excel isn't transferring over to Access.

Comment: Yes, a form would be great to do this with. Is the BETTER_CODES column the primary key column in the icd9_codes table? Meaning that every BETTER_CODE is unique?

Comment: That is correct, BETTER_CODES is a primary key of the table icd9_codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how this could be accomplished with the DLookup funtion VBA. You could place this code in a form button callback or a key press callback for the textbox where the search code is entered at.

```
Me.TextboxToDisplayDescription = Nz(DLookup("LONG_DESCRIPTION", "icd9_codes", "[BETTER_CODES] = '" & Me.TextboxToSearchWith & "'"), "Invalid Code")
```

The "Nz" function around the DLookup function is not required but, it will prevent a "Invalid Use of Null" error if the user happened to enter a code that does not exist in the icd9_codes table.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work, but it did point me in the right direction. By coincidence I had a friend walking by that ended up helping me. We ended up with this
 `Dim db As Database, rs As Recordset, strSQL As String
    Set db = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "SELECT icd9_codes.LONG_DESCRIPTION FROM icd9_codes WHERE BETTER_CODES = '001.0'"
    MsgBox (strSQL)
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    Me.display_box.Value = rs!LONG_DESCRIPTION
`
I've been able to get this working, but I'd like to know your thoughts on this version!

Comment: Ah, yes, my mistake! I didn't realize that the better codes field was a string. I put single quotes around the "Me.TextboxToSearchWith" in the DLookup function which should make it work now. But, if the version your co-worker gave works, that's great. Looks like either way will work but, my version is only 1 line of code which will help keep things cleaner.

Comment: @SamSlaughterbeck suggestion is good, as it's down to one formula and doesn't rely on opening a database and recordset.  You could also just place the dlookup directly into a control box on the form, and avoid any VBA.  (just omit the "me." reference)

Comment: Yeah good points. So I've reworked with Sam's suggestion, and got it working so I'll mark it as a solution. Unfortunately I was forced to abandon this endeavor and now have a new problem I can't figure out and will probably be posting about soon....